# Cache data from external API in an orchestrated manner

Tags: api, caching, mocking, external, amazon-mws

I am building an application which uses the Amazon MWS API.
The API has limits for how frequently you can hit it.

I am looking for a tool that can act as a reverse-proxy, save the MWS API responses, and eventually masquerade as the MWS API without ever hitting it, returning only responses from the cache.

Some tools do this, but what I need is a bit more complicated.

Say I request a report from Amazon MWS:

1. I'll call RequestReport
2. I'll get a ReportRequestId back
3. I'll start server polling GetReportRequestList to find out what the current status of the report request is. The report request will go likely go through the statuses *SUBMITTED* then *DONE*, but it could also be set to *ERROR* or *CANCELLED*
4. When the report request status returned by GetReportRequestList is *DONE*, I can finally call GetReport and get the data.

The behavior from step 3 is what I'm trying to replicate.

This external API cache should be able to produce different results for the same request: the first response should yield *SUBMITTED* and then the second response should yield *DONE*.

I should be able to easily configure these flows as I wish, setting the responses I want for the 1st, 2nd, nth request.

I would like this tool to necessitate minimal configuration, I do not want to configure routes or anything, I want it to automatically cache everything and then return everything from the cache, never flushing it.

Also, I need this level of control over what's returned in a response, depending on the count of requests done up to that point.

Comment: It sounds like you want to have a process running in front of MWS that does the API calls to it, logs the responses, and then your app queries this process?   I'm not aware of an service that would do just what you're looking for, but you could write it yourself.  I did something similar but didn't have a need to cache all the MWS responses.  I just had a process running on a timer or started via a trigger that submitted a report and looped until the report was complete, then retrieved the report.  Honestly never ran into any problems with throttling.

Comment: That's probably what I will resort to. It isn't so much about throttling as it is about convenience. I have a procedure where I add an Amazon account to my application, copying a lot of data from it and this takes a while. I have to run the procedure over and over again to perfect it, so it would be faster if I could have the responses cached and it would also be safe because I'd be serving the same exact data I get back from MWS.

Comment: Yeah, got it.  So an easy thing could be using MWS scratchpad.  Copy/paste the responses out of that and dump them into a database.  Then you could play around in development against your database until you get your processes perfected.   Throttling is not really a concern in all my years using MWS.  Just don't check 10 times a second, more like once every minute!